# Using CacheCow with asp.net MVC kendoUI

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc, cachecow

I've been looking into installing CacheCow ( https://github.com/aliostad/CacheCow  ) , by just applying the nuget package and then adding:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new CacheCow.Server.CachingHandler(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));
```

to my global config file. Once i do this though, none of my grids will refresh properly, they all cache old values regardless of new data being made available or not.  I've used the header:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]  
public JsonResult _GetProjectList([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return Json(data.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

for outputcache at the top, but that doesn't seem to help.  Anyone have any experience using cachecow with kendo datasources, and how to get them to work with each other?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this as a solution.

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]  
public JsonResult _GetProjectList([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    //force the response to not cache the results. 
    this.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);


    //some code here......
    return Json(data.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I had to do this a while ago when I noticed that some of the Kendo widgets weren't updating their datasources correctly. (they did update when I turned off browser caching within the dev tools of the browser).

Although I haven't worked with that particular package hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: thanks for the idea, but that didn't fix my problem unfortunately.  I'm guessing your line does the same thing as my attribute for the most part.  CacheCow seems to be ignoring that setting, and i don't see anywhere in their documentation on how to change that